# How to determine the approximate order of the strength of nuclear force from Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, textbook-erratum

Today I came across a question , where I was asked to find the Strength of nuclear force from Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle...

Please can anyone help me out...
I have come across a solution which I think is not correct as far as the calculations are involved...[image]

Comment: What if I want to get the magnitude of the energy associated

Comment: Isn't it already written ? I didnt understand what you are asking for ?

Comment: The value comes out as 52keV and not 10MeV

Comment: @ArthurMorgan  $E_k$ isn't even close to 10 MeV. The calculation is ~50 keV.

Comment: Where did you find that example?

Comment: In a book which is available in our country

Comment: The diameter of a nucleon is 0.8 fm, not 10. So that's a factor 100 right there.

Comment: @JEB That's for a nucleon, not a nucleus. Further that's the electric charge radius (not diameter), but what matters in a nucleus is mostly the effective range of the pion, $\hbar c / m_\pi c^2 \approx 1.3\rm\,fm$. More detail in an answer-in-progress.

Comment: @rob Oops. Xiangdong Ji has a nice PDF on the internet addressing this topic, but I can't find it. BTW: isn't the radius more appropriate, because $\Delta p$ has $\bar p = 0$, so the order of $p$ is the radius of a sphere in momentum space?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this without using macroscopic units --- sometimes even experts can do silly things with scientific notation.
We'll set

- $\hbar c \approx 0.2\rm\,GeV\,fm$ ([reference](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?hbcmevf))
- $M_\text{nucleon}c^2 \approx 1\rm\,GeV$
- $\Delta x \approx 10\rm\,fm $

Note that this is kind of a large nucleus.  The effective radius of a nucle*on* is closer to $\rm1\,fm$, and since nucleons in a nucleus are close-packed then the radius of a nucleus with mass number $A$ is pretty close to $A^{1/3}\rm\,fm$. But since your question is about orders of magnitude, we'll leave it there.

The uncertainty in the momentum --- and therefore an order-of-magnitude estimate for the typical magnitude of the momentum --- is

\begin{align}
\Delta p \Delta x &\gtrsim \hbar
\\
\Delta p c &\gtrsim \frac{\hbar c}{\Delta x}
= \frac{200\rm\,MeV\,fm}{10\rm\,fm} 
= 20\rm\,MeV
\end{align}

This is small compared to the nucleon mass, so we can use the non-relativistic kinetic energy:

\begin{align}
E = \frac{p^2}{2M} &= \frac{(pc)^2}{2 Mc^2}
\\ &= \frac{(20\rm\,MeV)^2}{2000\rm\,MeV} = 0.2\rm\,MeV.
\end{align}

Doubling $\Delta x$ brings this energy estimate down to $50\rm\,keV$, as you have correctly computed; your photographed text is wrong.

Note that the statement of the uncertainty principle,

$$
\sigma_p \sigma_x \geq \hbar / 2
$$

is an *in*equality, so a simple way to interpret this discrepancy is to claim that a nucleon rattling around in a nucleus isn't in a minimum-uncertainty state, which isn't too surprising.
An interesting reversal of this homework problem would be to build a smarter model of a nucleon in a nucleus --- say a three-dimensional square well with the correct radius and an empirically-observed nucleon separation energy of 8-ish MeV --- and compute $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ for that solution, to see by what margin the uncertainty principle is actually obeyed.
What you'll find is that the ground state for a square-well wavefunction is pretty close to a minimum-uncertainty wavepacket, but because of the way that the square well wavefunctions are quantized, there's no simple connection between the depth of the well $V$ and the kinetic energy $E-V \approx p^2/2m$.

For what it's worth, this approach works much better for electronic energy levels:

\begin{align}
\Delta x_\text{atom} &\sim 0.1\rm\,nm \\
\Delta p c \geq \frac{\hbar c}{2\Delta x} &= \frac{197\rm\,eV\,nm}{2\times 0.1\rm\,nm} \approx 10^3\rm\,eV \\
E \sim \frac{(\Delta p c)^2}{2m_\text{electron}c^2} &= 
\frac{10^6\rm\,eV^2}{2\times\frac12\times10^6\rm\,eV} \approx 1\rm\,eV
\end{align}

That's probably because the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) guarantees that the kinetic and potential energies in the electrical interaction between an electron and its nucleus have the same magnitude, while the relationship for the nuclear potential is a lot messier.